# CodeBuild with parallel builds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, buildspec

I'm using CodeBuild with this syntax in buildspec:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - pwd
  build:
    commands:
    - echo "hi" && sleep 50
    - echo "hi" && sleep 20
    batch:
      fast-fail: false
      build-list:
        - identifier: build1
        - identifier: build2
```

It should be running in parallel but run sequentially.

What have I missed?

Try an example above

Comment: Why do you think it should run in parallel?

Comment: sleep 50 and sleep 20

Comment: Still don't understand why would sleep 50 and sleep 20 lead to parallel execution?

Comment: According to aws docs, batch type build-list should run in parallel